# Increasing a variable value with onClick on javascript and showing new value on HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, onclick

I am coding a fan site for a game called League of Legends and my users, who would like to create character builds, should click on skill icons and give it a point. (maximum 30 points)

A live example is here:
http://www.solomid.net/masteries.php

You basically have 30 points. When you click on a skill image, it adds a point to that skill.

Since I am a beginner in JS & jQuery, I would like to ask:

1. I can currently make a div and give it the "onClick="alert('I am clicked.');" parameter so it alerts when someone clicks the div. I need to update this a bit, let's say:

   1. User clicks the div. (e.g let's say it is currently 0/4 skill value)
   2. 0 increases by 1, becomes 1/4.
   3. User repeats this 3 times, gives 4/4 points to skill.
   4. This value should be posted to PHP page, hence, saved in form.

   How can I do this? Could you please give me an example how it works in jQuery?
2. As you can see, when you click on skills, it generates an int value after the hash string.

For example; #0332000000000000003000000000000000000000000000000

The meaning of this string is,
[skill1_value] [skill2_value] [skill3_value] ... [skillLast_value]

So if you see a value like this;

## 30001 (the rest are 0)

It means, user clicked 3 times on "first skill", didn't click on the next 3 skills. Clicked once on the fifth skill.

Instead of posting every single form value to PHP, I will only post the integer value of hash string. The rest of the calculations will be done with PHP.

**TL;DR Version**

1. Imagine 3x div. (div1, div2, div3)
2. Imagine each div containing a visible number value on screen. (val1, val2, val3)
3. All values are 0 by default.
4. If you click on div1, val1 value should be increased by 1. If you click in div2, val2 value should be increased by 1 and so on.
5. The new values should always be shown in HTML output.
   6 When user clicks on "Save", it should generate a string like the following:
   (val1 + val2 + val3 ...) (e.g 716)

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know it's a beginner question, so links to articles would also be useful.

Comment: I'll be honest - I looked at the page and it looks quite full-featured already. Is the AJAX post the only thing you don't have working or is this not your page?

Comment: No, it's not my page. It's the thing I am trying to code.

I currently made text-input boxes for every skill. Users has to click on box and insert a value themself. I want this to be done by clicking on skills only, would save my users lots of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example with max values and a cap on how many points you have to use.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Q2SS/2/

```
var remaining = 5;
var MAX_VALUE = 4;
$('.clickybox').click( function(el) {
    if (remaining == 0)
        return;
    var resBox = $(this).find('.result');
    var curVal = resBox.attr('_data-value');
    if (!curVal)
        curVal = 0;
    if (curVal >= MAX_VALUE)
        return;
    curVal++;
    remaining--;
    resBox.text(curVal + '/4');
    resBox.attr('_data-value', curVal);

    alert($('.result').map(function() { 
        var s = $(this).attr('_data-value'); 
        if (s == undefined) s = '0'; 
        return s; 
    }).get().join('-'));
});
```

EDIT: Updated for clarity

Comment: EDIT: Seems like you did it while I post this comment. Thanks alot.

Comment: @AnılÜnal: Is it clearer now? Try the fiddle, you will see that after every click it will pop the concatenated values - generated in the `alert` line of the method you see here. It takes all the `result` class divs, grabs the attribute I'm storing its value in (`_data-value`) and adds it to the string - it also makes sure you get a value, if it hasn't been clicked `attr` returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/THubm/4/

And the code:

```
$(function(){
    var numerators = $('.numerator');

    $('.title').click(function(){
        var numerator = $(this).next().children();
        var newVal = +numerator.text() + 1;
        numerator.text(newVal);

        var hash = '';
        numerators.each(function(){
            hash += $(this).text();
        });
        alert(hash);
    });
});
```

Rather than explain every part, let me know what questions you have.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I really appreciate this. I didn't understood a single part. 

On newVal variable, the first skill number should always be the first number. In yours, if you click the first skill twice, it alerts (200), if you click the second skill once, it alerts (120). It should be (210). Would you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I've fixed the code. But if you don't understand "a single part", then you clearly haven't spent any time trying to learn jQuery on your own. There are plenty of tutorials out there, as well as the very well-written jQuery documentation, that would make this example understandable pretty quickly.

Comment: I haven't learn jQuery before. I usually code on PHP, SQL, AS3 etc. Sometimes I need little javascript functions like this. However, I am planning on studying on jQuery as soon as possible - been searching for a good e-book. Would you recommend any e-books or any tutorial websites?

Comment: I don't have any specific suggestions. One of the great things about jQuery is that it is very easy to learn. I'd recommend trying to find a book that teaches both the basics of pure JS along with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

During an div's `onclick` event, the `this` keyword is by default bound to that div element, so you always know which div fired the event. I'm guessing you have some JavaScript object that collects the values, so you can do something like this:

```
onDivClick = function() {
    skillObj[this.id].value++;  // Increments the stored value
    this.innerHTML = skillObj.getDisplayValue(this.id);  // Updates the div text
};
div1.onclick = onDivClick;
div2.onclick = onDivClick; // Same function can be assigned to multiple divs
```

The details may change in your implementation but that's the general idea. The "Save" button can just loop through `skillObj` and build up a string, then it's up to you to send that string to the server.

I don't use jQuery, but doing something like this doesn't really need it. If you need specific jQuery help for this then you should consider asking a more specific question.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Store your skill-clicks in a hash or in a hidden field. It will start off as a string of 000. You can then increase the correct digit based on what div was clicked.

Somehow, you will need to keep the mapping somewhere between divs (skills) and digit placement (index) in your hash string.

There is also a limitation of only being able to have skill level between 0..9 as you're limited to only one digit.